# Why are some of my elements jumping when my css transition are initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I'm creating a widget with animated transitions. On click, the circular elements hidden behind the main circle element should expand outward from center.

My initial styles position these animated elements correctly, my active styles position these elements correctly, but something is making half of them start in an odd position when the active class is toggled.

Why is this happening ?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d70q5q2j/1/).

The CSS code :

```
#al_stage {
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:650px;
    height:650px;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.al_container {
    position:relative;
    padding:70px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:255px;
    display:block;
    background:#5c76a3;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.al_scale {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
.al_circle {
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.al_wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.al_center {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
}
.al_bubble {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    display:block;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
.al_md {
    width:76%;
    height:76%;
    margin-left:-38%;
    margin-top:-38%;
    margin-right:initial;
    margin-bottom:initial;
}
.al_sm {
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
    margin-left:-30%;
    margin-top:-30%;
    margin-right:initial;
    margin-bottom:initial;
}
.active {
    -webkit-transition:left 1.0s, right 1.0s, top 1.0s, bottom 1.0s, margin-left 1.0s, margin-top 1.0s, margin-bottom 1.0s, margin-right 1.0s;
    transition:left 1.0s, right 1.0s, top 1.0s, bottom 1.0s, margin-left 1.0s, margin-top 1.0s, margin-bottom 1.0s, margin-right 1.0s;
}
.al_twelve.active {
    top:initial;
    bottom:100%;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
.al_six.active {
    top:100%;
    bottom:initial;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:1%;
}
.al_three.active {
    left:100%;
    right:initial;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:0;
}
.al_nine.active {
    right:100%;
    left:initial;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-left:0;
}
.bubble_container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
.deg30 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.deg30 .al_scale {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.deg60 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.deg60 .al_scale {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after another round of fiddling, I've solved the problem by being a little more verbose with the positioning. Here are the primary changes:

```
.al_bubble {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}
.al_md {
  width: 76%;
  height: 76%;
}
.al_sm {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
.al_three.al_md,
.al_six.al_md {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -38%;
  margin-left: -38%;
}
.al_three.al_sm,
.al_six.al_sm {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -30%;
  margin-left: -30%;
}
.al_twelve.al_md,
.al_nine.al_md {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -38%;
  margin-right: -38%;
}
.al_twelve.al_sm,
.al_nine.al_sm {
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -30%;
  margin-right: -30%;
}
.active {
  -webkit-transition: left 1.0s, right 1.0s, top 1.0s, bottom 1.0s, margin-left 1.0s, margin-top 1.0s, margin-bottom 1.0s, margin-right 1.0s;
  transition: left 1.0s, right 1.0s, top 1.0s, bottom 1.0s, margin-left 1.0s, margin-top 1.0s, margin-bottom 1.0s, margin-right 1.0s;
}
.al_twelve.active {
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.al_six.active {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.al_three.active {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.al_nine.active {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

And here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d70q5q2j/2/)